# Copy/Clone Stream in a loop...

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I am fundamentally doing something wrong here within this loop. The first time through the loop, the Stream works fine, but subsequent times through the loop fail with the Stream being corrupted. I know am probably doing something silly. I tried to set the updateTemplate to 0 each time but the InputStream doesn't support the seek. I am basically appending multiple forms that are filled in onto a List here. Any suggestions would be appreciated, especially ones that would result in better performance.

```
...
files.Add(PDFhelper.fillTemplate(template, mappings));

foreach (Update u in myObject.Updates)
{
    mappings = this.GenerateFieldMappings(u);
    Stream output = new MemoryStream();
    template.CopyTo(output);
    files.Add(PDFhelper.fillTemplate(output, mappings)); //First time stream is good  

}

return PDFhelper.MergeFiles(files);

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is one solution I found. although, I don't find it very efficient. It does get the job done.

```
files.Add(PDFhelper.fillTemplate(mainTemplate, mappings));
byte[] templateData = updateTemplate.ReadToEnd();

foreach (Update u in myobject.Updates)
{
    mappings = this.GenerateFieldMappings(u);
    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
    output.Write(templateData, 0, templateData.Length);
    output.Position = 0;
    files.Add(PDFhelper.fillTemplate(output, mappings));

 }

 return PDFhelper.MergeFiles(files);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you add the `using` keyword or add output.Dispose() at end of loop? See [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/csharpgeneral/thread/b07a3cad-22cc-450c-981e-ea91655a2695).

```
files.Add(PDFhelper.fillTemplate(template, mappings));

foreach (Update u in myObject.Updates)
{
    mappings = this.GenerateFieldMappings(u);
    using(Stream output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        template.CopyTo(output);
        files.Add(PDFhelper.fillTemplate(output, mappings)); //First time stream is good
    }
}

return PDFhelper.MergeFiles(files);
```